# Bash script to import RootCA and set it to Always Trust from Server

Tags: macos, bash, server.app, certificate

I am working on a way to import a RootCA into the login keychain of OS X and set it to always trust, the cert is located on a file share server.

I am relatively new to the whole Bash scripting scene and have been actively researching this issue for a few weeks now with some success. I have been able to import and trust a RootCA locally, but unable to reach out to a server and import the cert.

Here is what I currently have:

```
sudo security add-trusted-cert -d -r trustAsRoot -k $HOME/Library/Keychains/login.keychain $HOME/Desktop/rootCA
```

When I replace "$HOME/Desktop/rootCA" with my server path, I get prompted for a password, then receive a message:

> Error reading file "*Server path*"

I have tried to SSH to the server and have been greeted with "Connection refused on port 22"... I don't have access to manage this server either.

Any thoughts?

Comment: `security` can't read the cert and keychain file from a remote server, it can only read them from local disk. You don't say what _"Server path"_ is in your output specifically -- is it an standard file system path to an NFS mount? An `afs` path? It has to be a path to a local file.

Comment: Oh, so I cannot pull a cert from a remote server and add it to keychain via BASH?
Is it possible to download the cert to a temporary folder and then import to the keychain? Same script, but separate lines?

Comment: You can "pull it", you just can't do it in one line. You could use `ssh` to extract it from the remote machine's keychain, save it to a file and then `scp` it to the machine where you want to import it.

Comment: Ok, so the certificate is located on a Windows server, will that cause any issues?

Comment: Probably. Remote access to Windows machines sucks. You need a way to pull it, remotely, from that machine to your Mac. That's probably a whole question unto itself.

Comment: Dang.... Well, I will see what I can dig up with that. Thanks for the help on this!